# Geofencing push notifications in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, geolocation

Can i send a push notification when the contact enter the location and satisfy additional conditions, like for instance owns a membership card or age range?

Basically I don't want to send to everyone entering the location but I want to target only those matching specific attributes of a data extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, Geofence Notifications are *not* push notifications.  They are downloaded and triggered upon fence transitions.

Take a look at the SDK's convenience methods for `should show notification` (ref. [Should Show Notification Listener](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/6.3/reference/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/notifications/NotificationManager.html#setShouldShowNotificationListener(com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationManager.ShouldShowNotificationListener))).  This method will be called whenever the SDK is going to display a notification.  You will be provided the Notification Message (ref. [Notification Message](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/6.3/reference/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/notifications/NotificationMessage.html)) from which you can glean whatever data necessary along with data you know about the consumer in order to make a `true|false` determination on whether or not the message should be displayed.

Also, documentation & example applications can be found https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/mobile-push-sdk.htm